# How to add multiple expand triggers to Vuetify Datatable? (Vue 2)

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a data table in which one of the columns is an icon. Clicking it will expand a row. This works but I need another expandable row with another icon that can expand this row.

My code looks like this:

```
<v-data-table
      //typical data table stuff like headers etc
    >
  <template #item="{ item, expand, isExpanded }">
 <tr> //other columns
  <td>
   <v-chip v-if="!isExpanded" color="indigo" @click="expand(true)"
                ><v-icon color="white" dark small>
                  mdi-chevron-down
                </v-icon></v-chip
              >
              <v-chip
                v-if="isExpanded"
                color="indigo"
                dark
                @click="expand(false)"
                ><v-icon color="white" dark small>
                  mdi-chevron-up
                </v-icon></v-chip
              >
     </td>
  </tr>
  <template #expanded-item="{ item }">
          <td class="expanded" colspan="12">
            <v-chip
              v-for="customer in item.customers"
              :key="customer.id"
              pill
              darken-3
              color="primary"
              outlined
              class="ma-md-1"
              >{{ customers[customer].name }}
            </v-chip>
          </td></template
        >
```

I tried copying the same mechanism to add another trigger and another expandable template but kept running into a lot of errors.
From what I see, it looks like the data-table is hardwired for one row. Is it possible to add one more icon trigger to expand one more row?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this effect by nesting `<v-data-table>`:

```
  <v-data-table :headers="dessertHeaders" :items="desserts" :expanded.sync="expanded" item-key="name" show-expand class="elevation-1">
      <template #expanded-item="{ headers, item }">
        <td :colspan="headers.length">
          <v-data-table :headers="customerHeaders" :items="item.customers" :single-expand="singleExpand" :expanded.sync="customersExpanded" item-key="name" show-expand class="elevation-1" hide-default-footer>
            <template #expanded-item="{ headers, item }">
        <td :colspan="headers.length">
          Nested Expanded Row for {{item.name}} with ID of {{item.id}}
        </td>
      </template>
      <template #item.data-table-expand="{ item, expand, isExpanded }">
        <v-chip color="indigo" dark @click="expand(!isExpanded)">
          <v-icon color="white" dark small>
            {{ isExpanded ? 'mdi-chevron-up' : 'mdi-chevron-down'}}
          </v-icon>
        </v-chip>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
    </td>
    </template>
    <template #item.data-table-expand="{ item, expand, isExpanded }">
      <v-chip color="indigo" dark @click="expand(!isExpanded)">
        <v-icon color="white" dark small>
          {{ isExpanded ? 'mdi-chevron-up' : 'mdi-chevron-down'}}
        </v-icon>
      </v-chip>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
```

[Sandbox Example](https://codepen.io/rustamd/pen/GRGJzLv) - Please note `customers` array defined in items, as well as second `expanded.sync` variable `customersExpanded`. As well as `hide-default-footer` attribute on nested table to remove/hide pagination panel.

Comment: Thank you. But in my case both the triggers are in the same level adjacent columns. The expandable rows are not nested but peers. So the problem is both have same parent template. But ```:expanded.sync``` can be bound to a single value.

Comment: @SanSolo Hmm, my first thought was to use `data-table-select` slot https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#slots-item.data-table-select since it's supposed to expose `expand` method, but it seems there is a bug, or documentation is wrong, as it does not expose the `expand` method, at least in the sandbox version(which should be latest Vuetify 2)... Let me see if I can come up with even hackier solution lol